# SSIS - Foreach loop using ado enumerator

Tags: foreach, ssis

I am using a For Each Loop with ADO Enumerator for retrieving large bunch of data from an Oracle database to a SQL Server. Inside the for each loop I have a Data Flow task, that has an OLE DB source and destination. The total of loops in general is between 900 and 1500. The average time of the loops is about 6 seconds, but sometimes I get some loops that last over 40 minutes!

What is the best approach to overcome these long time loops? **If a loop is over 30 seconds how can I to skip this one and continue to the next?**

[image]

**FILTER LIST** (code): SELECT [ID], [FILTER] FROM [tblFilter]

[image]

**tblFilter** (In SQL Server): more than 900 records

```
• Every day my table called tblProd has over 420000 records
• From this table I create a new table called tblFilter with 2 columns, ID and FILTER
• The ID is of type identity and the FILTER is a string from concatenating 400 records at a time from the column 'RNUM' (length = 11) of tblProd.
• Upon creating tblFilter I get over 900 records, where the filter field is a very big string.
```

This code is part of the OLE DB Source and used in a Variable name where 'FILTER1' is being replaced by the each of the FILTER from tblFILTER.

**Variable name**

```
SELECT 
    ..
FROM
    table1 T1
    INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    ...
WHERE 
    T1.RNUM IN ('FILTER1')
    ...
```

**Example of the 900 queries that is going to run after replacing** 'FILTER1'

```
SELECT 
    ..
FROM
    table1 T1
    INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    ...
WHERE 
    T1.RNUM IN ('20213504210','20213504252','20213504267', …)  -- 400 RNUM / FILTER
    ...
```

Regards
MJR

Comment: The first thing to do is work out whether you can avoid having a loop. Can you expand on what you are doing? _Inside the for each loop I have a Data Flow task_ what is this data flow task doing? Can you possibly just have one single data flow task outside the loop?

Comment: I just add an image to explain how the the for each loop is working.

Comment: Please add text as text, not pictures. Your picture doesn't really explain much but the text does. Can you explain what you are trying to do? (replicate changed data from Oracle?) Also please explain where the list comes from? is it from Oracle or somewhere else.

Comment: Are you trying to use your filter to limit the requested records? Try this instead... select * from (select x,y,x, Row_Number() over (order by [the identity column]) as rn from ....) as a where rn > [@rnCounter].   And then increment counter by your limit. Exit for loop when record count < limit. This will give you a consistent pull every time. And start [@rnCounter] = 0.

Comment: Just updated the post. What I need is to overcome querys that take more than 30 seconds and move to the next query in loop.

Comment: In that case you need to optimise the Oracle query - ensure that join columns and IN columns are indexed. Where does this list of IN values come from?

Comment: Sometimes it can can be quicker to simply copy the whole table locally and work locally.